# Can't access instance var from do block in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have this block for configuring the Mail gem.

```
Mail.defaults do 
  retriever_method :imap, :address    => @mail_settings[:address],
                          :port       => @mail_settings[:port],
                          :user_name  => @mail_settings[:username], 
                          :password   => @mail_settings[:password],
                          :enable_ssl => @mail_settings[:enable_ssl]   
end
```

@mail_settings is accessible and can be read outside of the do block but not inside. I'm newish to ruby so I'm trying to understand why. Right now, I'm getting this error (line 66 is the retriever_method line):

```
main.rb:66:in `block in set_mail_defaults': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

Strangely, this works:

```
address     = @mail_settings[:address]
port        = @mail_settings[:port]
user_name   = @mail_settings[:username]
password    = @mail_settings[:password]
enable_ssl  = @mail_settings[:enable_ssl]

Mail.defaults do 
  retriever_method :imap, :address    => address,
                          :port       => port, 
                          :user_name  => user_name,  
                          :password   => password,
                          :enable_ssl => enable_ssl   
end
```

Comment: The error is pointing towards `@mail_settings` being Nil. Verify that it isn't and the code should work.

Comment: The part you have shared is not sufficient...

Comment: Can you show whole code/file?

Comment: This snippet resides in a method called set_mail_defaults() within a very basic singleton. set_mail_defaults() is called from the constructor. The mail_settings hash is loaded from a yaml file within the constructor.

The issue has something to do with scope. I'm not able to use @mail_settings directly within the Mail.defaults block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Mail.defaults` method is defined as follows:

```
def self.defaults(&block)
    Configuration.instance.instance_eval(&block)
end
```

Which means that it evaluates the block within the singleton instance (`Configuration` includes the `Singleton` module) of `Configuration` which is not the context of the class you are working with and where `@mail_settings` resides.

To overcome this you can define a local variable to hold `@mail_settings` so that you can access it within the block:

```
m = @mail_settings
Mail.defaults do 
  retriever_method :imap, :address    => m[:address],
                          :port       => m[:port],
                          :user_name  => m[:username], 
                          :password   => m[:password],
                          :enable_ssl => m[:enable_ssl]   
end
```

Comment: Really helpful! That also explains what retriever_method is - a method of the Configuration singleton.

Answer (score 1):

`Mail.defaults`  is running `instance_eval` on the block ([source code](https://github.com/mikel/mail/blob/95ebfb703a3ba8e51ad2d2436b73ce28828ddcd3/lib/mail/mail.rb#L105)). This means that any instance variables you look up will be in the object that serves as the instance for the block. To get around this, assign the value of the instance variable to a local variable.

Comment: I tried assigning the @mail_settings hash to a local and that didn't work. While I was able to confirm the local was not nil, I still got the error whenever I tried to use the local hash within the Mail.defaults block.